# Why grep not function as expected with large file?

Tags: bash, grep

I am using grep to examine a pretty large log file (> 6GB). Each line of log has timestamp and in descending order of time. If I grep earlier date, it returns correctly.

```
$ grep '2017-11-30' log
...
```

However, if I grep later date, it only shows "Binary file log matches"

```
$ grep '2017-12-12' log
Binary file log matches
```

Why? and how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: Just a wild guess: try to use `grep -a`.

Comment: That works, thank you!